# Is it "clipart" or "clip art"?

Tags: spacing

What is a correct spelling - "**clipart**" or "**clip art**"?

Is there any difference in meaning?

May it be language specific, like American, British, Australian?

Maybe "**clip-art**"?

Comment: I say it's two words. So does my nearest dictionary.

Comment: May it be language specific, like American, British, Australian?

Comment: Can you look around your own industry and see what seems most common?

How could anything else matter?

Comment: 'Clip art (also clipart, clip-art)': [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clip_art)